# Perpendicular Vectors in 3D space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, vector-spaces, 3d

I was wondering whether given two Vector's **v0** and **v1** whether I could find the two perpendicular vectors at a given distance, **d**, from **v1**, perpendicular to the **v0**/**v1** line. I know that **v0** and **v1** will share an axis so the perpendiculars must also.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE5Ti.png)

How would I go about finding two vectors perpendicular to the **v0**/**v1** line, at a right angle either side of **v1** at distance **d**. The perp's would also be at **.z** = 0.0 in the example shown.

I know that i will always have axis aligned Vectors- but which axes in each case is unknown.

I assume this can be done with the directional vector of the two vectors?

Thanks in advance- hope this makes sense.

Comment: I might not totally get you. $\overrightarrow{v_1v_a}$ is perpendicular to $\overrightarrow{v_0v_1}$, but there's an infinite amount of vectors that suit this. What's the extra parameter that defines the poistion of $v_a$.

Comment: @Ruts **v0** and **v1** will have one axis the same. i.e. both on y = -6.1, or same x etc. Therefore we know the **vA** and **vB** will also have that axis. I think from normalising the **v1** - **v0** to get the direction i'll know which axis is the smae as the normalised vector will have 0.0 for that axis. Then I can treat that axis as the "up" axis, and do a cross product of the "up" and the **v1** to get **vA**... Something along these lines?